# Lookup field doesn't support some field types

Tags: 2013, lookup-column

Its looking more and more like you can't add additional fields that are anything other than string boxes (no person or yes/no etc) is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Person fields are themselves lookup fields so there's not really a workaround there, unfortunately. That's also why you can't use them in calculated columns; the only thing that the list actually stores is the primary key of the person in question (which is then referenced on, for instance, their MySite or the site collection user pages).

You could get around the Yes/No field issue by adding a calculated field which converts the Yes/No column (which is stored, I believe, as a single bit; i.e. the base value is either 1 or 0) into the literal words "Yes" or "No" (or, alternatively, "True" or "False"). Prior to SP2010 SP1 you could also just use a Choice field as a lookup but for reasons unknown to me Microsoft decided to disable that.